# SSH to specific computer behind a router if local IP is known

Tags: ssh, port

I'm hosting a number of websites out of different boxes behind a router; when I was only hosting one, it was simple enough to forward port 22 on to the hosting box and use that one as a remote server when developing inside my IDE. But I'm switching to multiple boxes, both to reduce server load and to make it easier to host in different languages, and I'm trying to figure out how I can tell my different servers to publish to different boxes while all using SSH. I know that I can command line SSH in on a specific port, allowing me to set up multiple forwards on my router and manually log in to each, but I wonder how that will play with an IDE's publishing suite, since it likely has less flexibility that command line. Maybe it's a dumb question, but is there a standard nomenclature for specifying a local address behind a router that's not so cumbersome?

Comment: Have you considered using a VPN into your network so that you can directly reach each machine once the VPN is up ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IDE isn't a total piece of crap, it should adhere to the configuration given in `~/.ssh/config`. Simply set each `Host` to point to the same `HostName` but a different `Port`. See the `ssh_config(5)` man page for details.